# Causal relationship between two set of random variables

Tags: statistics, graph-theory

I'm working on structural learning in Bayesian Networks.

Assume two types of random variables are given. class I: $x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n$ and class II:  $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$.

Generally, we can have a directed arc from $x_i$ to $y_j$ and vice versa.

Is there any application in which we know there is only one possible direction i.e., either we can go from $x_i$ variables to $y_j$ variables or we can only go from $y_j$ variables to $x_i$ variable?

Note, we don't know the direction a priori. The only thing we can assume is that there is one directional relationship (if any relationship exists) among two set of variables i.e., $x \rightarrow y$ or $y \rightarrow x$.

Can anyone give me some suggestions where I can find case studies in real world with such properties. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Diseases -> Death by a specific cause. 

For example $Diseases = \{\textrm{Heart Disease, Cancer, Alzheimer's}\}$ and $Deaths = \{\textrm{Heart Attack, Kidney Failure, Accidental Related Death}\}$

Comment: Thanks. In this example, we know Disease class leads to death. I am looking for an application that we do not know the causal direction in advance.

Comment: By such applications, I thought you may mean causation which should be inferred from a randomized experiment in prospective studies, but it does not relate to the direction but the connection.